# Deploying the same WSP file with a different name

Tags: solution-package, solution-deployment, farm-solution

I have created wsp file using Visual Studio 2010 that servers an application pages in site. My solution file name is "Portal.wsp".

I have already deploy this solution file on my server it running fine. but now my question is I want to deploy this solution file with the different name on the same server.

I want to create one solution for general use and another one is for testing purpose.

So ultimately my solution file is same but I want to serve it with two different name like "Portal.wsp" and "PortalTest.wsp"

Regards,

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This doesn't sound like something you would ever want to do.

Answer (score 6):

DON'T

There is no way this is going to turn out well.

Changing the name of the WSP isn't going to change anything. You'll still have the same:

- Solution Id
- Feature Folders and Ids
- Dlls (including the codebehind for your application pages)
- SharePoint Root files (including your application pages)

So in order for the new solution not to overwrite the old you have to change all of that, which is a lot of work and it's very likely that something will be missed.

With a Farm solution there is no way you can have both production and test on the same farm at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be an easy task. You'll need to create two VS solutions, and change the feature and package names/IDs so they're unique. Now you're managing two solutions which is a bad idea.

The ideal situation is to spin up another farm, ideally a testing farm (can be a single box/VM if you want) and test everything there, then roll the same WSP to production once it's ready. This does require additional resources, but it will be the best solution moving forward.

HTH

Comment: i appreciate ur solution to available it to another farm but client requirement is to do like this so i need to go with that so wht i need to do ?

Comment: Time to encourage the client to do what's right ;). A few more issues I just thought of copying the project. Resources in the layouts folder will overwrite each other since they're in the same folder structure. You need to rename all feature specific folders, then update your code to reference the new folder structure. Change the feature's XML file to change the name and ID.

Answer (score 0):

so you need to change feature id of wsp file and change name PortalTest.wsp are else it override existing portal.wsp feature.